# Using coordinate vector to find tuples so we get $x \in L$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, solution-verification

We have the matrix
$$
A=(a_1|a_2|a_3|a_4)=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -6 & -3 & -11\\
4 & 1 & 4 & 10\\
-1 & 5 & 13 & -6\\
-4 & 6 & 10 & -24
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the Q matrix from its QR-factorization:
$$
Q=(q_1|q_2|q_3|q_4)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{4}{7}& -\frac{2}{7} &\frac{5}{7}&  -\frac{2}{7} \\
\frac{4}{7} & \frac{5}{7} &  -\frac{2}{7}  &  -\frac{2}{7} \\
-\frac{1}{7} &\frac{4}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{4}{7}\\
-\frac{4}{7}& \frac{2}{7}& \frac{2}{7} & -\frac{5}{7}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
with basis $\mathcal{A}=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ and $\mathcal{Q}=(q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4)$.

I have to determine the (infinitely many) tuples $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4)\in \Bbb R^4$
for which the vector
$$
x=\lambda_1a_1+\lambda_2a_2+ \lambda_3a_3+ \lambda_4a_4
$$
lies on the line $L =\operatorname {span} \{q_4 \}$ stretched by the vector $q_4$.

I have got a hint to this problem. I have to find the coordinate vector $[x]_Q$  expressed by $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3, \lambda_4$ and then consider how the condition $x \in L$
can be expressed using this coordinate vector. I think I by my own can find $[x]_Q$ but I'm not totally sure how  the condition $x \in L$
can be expressed using this coordinate vector? I think that the definition is that a vector $v$ is in the $span(u_1,...,u_k)$ if the matrix $[u_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot \ u_k v]$ got no pivot position in last column. But how can I use this and the coordinate vector? Hope anybody can help?

Answer (score 1):

As $\det(A) \ne 0$, the columns of $A$ constitute a basis of $\mathbb{R^4}$.

Therefore, we can express *in a unique way*:

$$\mu_1 a_1+\mu_2 a_2+\mu_3 a_3+\mu_4 a_4 = q_4\tag{1}$$

In order to find coefficients $\mu_k$, we remark that (1) is equivalent to

$$\underbrace{(a_1|a_2|a_3|a_4)}_A\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1\\
\mu_2\\
\mu_3\\
\mu_4
\end{pmatrix}}_{M}=q_4 \ \iff \  M = A^{-1}q_4=\begin{pmatrix}
-5/14\\
-6/14\\
3/14\\
1/14
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore taking any multiple of this vector of coefficients $M$, you will "cover" Span($q_4$).

Comment: Any comment ? By the way, the fact that it is a QR decomposition plays no role.

Comment: Nice, thank you that makes sense:-)